# Button styling using CSS

Tags: css

I have a button on my web-page.

```
<button id="button" type="button">Show</button>
```

I want my button in blue color and if possible to have rounded corners. How can I do that?? I am really new to styling.

Comment: if you copied and paste the tag you missed '>'! try border-radius: 50%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```css
#button {
    background: blue;
    border-radius: 35px;
    border: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qLZKs/

Answer (score 1):

corrected your MARK UP

```
 <button class="button">SHOW</button> /*..you were missing the >   ...*/
```

and css

```
 .button{
background-color:blue;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yLrBS/)**

Comment: Your _correction_ changed the id to a class and made the value uppercase! For support across more browsers you could add `-webkit-border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius:10px; border-radius:10px;`

Comment: @Moob css prefixes should generally be avoided where possible - and here, they're [pretty unnecessary](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius).

Comment: Also - replacing the id with a class is - when it comes to styling - a **good** habit to get into, since ID's have other effects. You may discover one day that you want to have several buttons in the DOM (even if hidden), and although CSS is quite happy for an ID selector to match multiple items, many JS libraries are not, which can cause problems.

Comment: We don't know the OP's requirements so changing existing code could be unconstructive (aside from correcting the missing close bracket). You could not bother with the className at all. I'd consider it good practice to include the browser prefixes (annoying as they are) and whilst `border-radius` is well supported you might have visitors on older iOS and Android devices.

Comment: @Moob: caniuse estimates those browsers account for less than 0.1%, i.e. virtually irrelevant - especially since missing border-radius isn't a critical flaw, just slightly ugly.  By comparison, IE8, which doesn't support it at all, is still at 6+%.  YMMV - but your site should be usable without border radius anyhow, and if it is, don't sweat the 0.1%.  Since any code you (plan to) write now lives for more than today, the average impact will be lower still.  Finally, there are [better](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) [solutions](http://cssprefixer.appspot.com/) anyhow.

Comment: Fair enough - its practically pointless. I was simply trying to be thorough.